# WebRTC connection with different networks

Tags: webrtc

I use this script for connect https://github.com/feross/simple-peer & connect 3 devices, on each of them 2 peers are opening, meaning they all connect each other. When I launch connection on 3 devices at home - all is working stable. But when devices are located remotely - at least one pair connection is getting lost.
I tried to use this list of servers, but it did not help & affected longer connection time.
What can be a reason for loosing connection?

Comment: I've been advised to establish my own stan & turn servers, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use turn server for this, This link can give an idea how to install and configure a simple turn server.https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html